# Multiple counts in one request

Tags: mongoose

I have the following code in my app :

```
const response = {
    created: await eventModel.count({ author: uid }).exec(),
    participated: await eventModel.count({ participants: uid }).exec(),
    interested: await eventModel.count({ interested: uid }).exec()
};
```

I want to know **how to have the same output with only one request**.

Here is the model :

```
const eventModel = mongoose.model("Event", new mongoose.Schema({
    author: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    interested: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    participants: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    title: String
}));
```

Is there a way to do this properly ?

Comment: How are you collections and models setup?

Comment: @MikeTung I've updated my post. Is this what you were asking for ?

Comment: see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you need to list what you have, what your input is, what your wanted output is and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Mike Tried to make it clearer. I hope it's better

Answer (score 1):

Without much of a clearer explanation if your question is `how do I get data from mongo and only make 1 query for a given criteria?` then here's how.

```
const eventModelCounts = eventModel.aggregate(
                     [

                         { $group : { _id : { author: uid, participants: uid, interested: uid },  uid: { $sum: 1 }  }}

                     ]

                    ).exec(function(err,data){
                        count = data;
                        console.log("this is data aggregate:",data);

                        callback();
                    });
```

essentially you apply an aggregation on the fields on interest.